# Using curl in a bash script and getting curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: linux, bash, curl, awk

So I have a very simple bash script that is curl'ing to an auth server for a header. The header url is written to a var and then used in the next curl call. When using the var set in the first curl call I am getting "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL". I am able to echo the var and all looks good, I am even able to reset the var (in my example below) and it works.

**The Bash script**

```
URL=$(curl -i -X GET -H "X-Auth-User: MyUserna,e" -H "X-Auth-Key: MyAPIKey" "https://urlToAuthServer.tld/auth/v1.0/" | grep "X-Storage-Url:" | awk '{print $2}')

curl -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: MyAuthTok" "${URL}/folder/myfile.txt" -o ./myfile.txt
```

**When running the above example I get:**

```
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

**The URL var looks like this (no illegal chars)**

```
https://somesecureurl.com/auth/AUTH_67383834-45245453-g34g34t5-34534
```

**When I do this in terminal it works:**

> $ URL=$(curl -i -X GET -H "X-Auth-User: MyUserna,e" -H "X-Auth-Key: MyAPIKey" "https://urlToAuthServer.tld/auth/v1.0/" | grep "X-Storage-Url:" | awk '{print $2}')
>
> $ echo $URL
>
> https://somesecureurl.com/auth/AUTH_67383834-45245453-g34g34t5-34534

Now I copy and paste the string and reasign it to URL like so (again all in terminal):

```
>$ URL="https://somesecureurl.com/auth/AUTH_67383834-45245453-g34g34t5-34534"
>$ curl -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: MyAuthTok" "${URL}/folder/myfile.txt" -o ./myfile.txt
```

It works.

So why am I getting the "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL" error in the first example?

**Update**
I ran this:
`printf %s "$URL" | xxd`

Here is the output (addressed changed up you get the idea)

```
0000000: 6874 7470 733a 2f2f 6461 6c30 352e 6f62  https://server.ob
0000010: 6a65 6374 7374 6f72 6167 652e 736f 6674  jectstorage.lite
0000020: 6c61 7965 722e 6e65 742f 7631 2f41 5554  sabers.com/v1/AUT
0000030: 485f 6665 3235 3339 3434 2d38 6433 322d  H_aE2563981-7d32-
0000040: 3432 3138 2d61 6566 632d 6665 6638 3465  4201-bdoi-fef94a
0000050: 6166 3331 6232 0d                        ag11c8.
```

Comment: Any whitespace, newlines, hidden characters in the url? Try with `printf %s "$URL" | xxd`.

Comment: @choroba, I am getting a "." at the end like so:
0000050: 6166 3331 6232 0d                        af31b2.

thats the last line in the output.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The $URL contains a `\r` (CR) at the end (`0d`). Remove it with

```
URL=${URL%$'\r'}
```

before using it with `curl`.

Comment: I understand that parameter expansion with % expands `$'\r'` into a pattern and then deletes that pattern from the URL. But why is the $ needed before the '\r'?

Comment: @Noumenon: Because `'\r'` is two characters, backslash and `r`, while `$'\r'` is one character, the CR. `$'...'` are different quotes than `'...'`.

Comment: Worked for me as well, I am wondering why curl cannot do it on its own.

Comment: @AdamSiemion: Because it would break calls to urls actually containing the character (even if there are probably not many of them).

Comment: @choroba if there are such URLs then they are not supported by curl, curl then just fails and does not make any request

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but it was caused by me having created the script through Windows, which meant that the end of line had an unnecessary \r.

A simple dos to unix conversion fixed it.

```
dos2unix <scriptname>
```

Answer (score 3):

stripping away trailing \r

```
tr -d '\r' < test.sh > testWithoutR.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an enter at the end of the file. Try to remove it or delete it, note that the enter character is not something view-able....