# curl not working in bashscript

Tags: bash, curl

I have a script which contains:

```
TEST=`curl -v  -X GET http://xxx/v2/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${DCD}`
TEST2="curl -v  -XGET http://xxx/v2/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${DCD}"
echo "output"
echo ${TEST}
echo "output2"
echo ${TEST2}
```

This is the output of TEST and TEST1:

```
* Illegal characters found in URL
* Closing connection -1
output
        ##empty
output2
curl -v -XGET http://xxx:5000/v2/proj1/base/manifests/sha256:a1f97fd03ec62888fb315745cde69acb7c98d0fae7xxx
```

If I copy the content of the output2 (curl -v...) and execute it than it works fine (that is what I try to do in output1). So it seems that the command is filled in correctly. But The execution of that command (what happens in output1) seems to fail with: Illegal character found in URL.

I really don't have a clue what is going wrong

Whole content of script with `cat -A`

```
#!/bin/sh$
#ENV VAR to set in Jenkins Job$
PROJECT="proj1"$
IMAGE="base"$
TAG="1.2"$
$
# Find Docker-Content-Digest$
DCD=`curl -v -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET http://xxx:5000/v2/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${TAG} 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}'`$
$
# Delete tag in registry using DCD$
# I just want to execute the command belowe but gave the illegal argument erros so tried some debugging with this$
TEST=`curl -v -X GET http://xxx:5000/v2/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${DCD}`$
$
TEST2="curl -v -XGET http://xxx:5000/v2/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${DCD}"$
echo "output"$
echo ${TEST}$
echo "output2"$
echo ${TEST2}$
$
```

Comment: can you `cat -A` your file to see if there is something fishy in there?

Comment: @fedorqui Added to my question (echo ${DCD} gave a right output)

Comment: Uhms, so no bad character seems to be around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
DCD=${DCD%$'\r'}
```

After the command DCD=`curl -v...

So it seemed to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018899/using-curl-in-a-bash-script-and-getting-curl-3-illegal-characters-found-in-ur) question.