# Error using curl in jenkins shell

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, docker-registry

I curl the api to get the docker-content-digest

```
curl -k -v --silent -H+  Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json -X GET https://xxx/v2/proj/image/manifests/latest
awk {print ($3)}
+ grep Docker-Content-Digest
+
```

I say: DCD = the digest which is found

```
DCD=sha256:e8e7df98e780885012a05dc468fc5f60d30ce51062e09e1bc82f9644d20de9d9
    +
```

Here I perform `DCDN="${DCD%$'\r'}"` which I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018899/using-curl-in-a-bash-script-and-getting-curl-3-illegal-characters-found-in-ur):

```
DCDN=sha256:e8e9df98e780885012a05dc468fc5f60d30ce51062e09e1bc82f9644d20de9d9
```

I also check if it ends with 0d which seems to be (issue?)
Herefor I perform: `printf %s "$DCDN" | xxd`

```
+ printf %s sha256:e8e9df98e780885012a05dc468fc5f60d30ce51062e09e1bc82f9644d20de9d9
+ xxd
0000000: 7368 6132 3536 3a65 3865 3764 6639 3865  sha256:e8e9df98e
0000010: 3738 3038 3835 3031 3261 3035 6463 3436  780885012a05dc46
0000020: 3866 6335 6636 3064 3330 6365 3531 3036  8fc5f60d30ce5106
0000030: 3265 3039 6531 6263 3832 6639 3634 3464  2e09e1bc82f9644d
0000040: 3230 6465 3964 390d                      20de9d9.
```

Because when I try to curl the output of my DCD after the URL it seems not to work in the right way... (It works fine if I do a copy past of the command and run it. But not in the jenkinsshell)

```
curl -k -v --silent -X GET https://xxx/v2/proj/image/manifests/latest/sha256:e8e9df98e780885012a05dc468fc5f60d30ce51062e09e1bc82f9644d20de9d9
* Illegal characters found in URL
* Closing connection -1
```

Comment: The byte represented in hex 0d is carriage-return, which is indeed illegal in a URL. The `%$'\r'` _should_ have removed it but apparently didn't. Copy-and-paste does work because copy copies only visible characters and carriage-return is not visible. You could try `${DCD%?}` to remove the last char _without_ checking it; this is a heavyhanded approach but might work.