# Illegal characters found in URL return by Unity WWW class

Tags: c#, url, unity-game-engine, web

I am getting very strange problem I have the url

```
http://localhost:5001/vr
```

When I directly assign this url to my inspector and then pass to WWW class, it works correctly but as I am getting the same url through text file using this code:

```
string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/" + urlFile;
string urls = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string[] url = urls.Split('\n');
string getURL = url[0];//this is the url
string doneURL = url[1];
```

I am getting this error in www class

> Illegal characters found in URL

There is nothing illegal I have logged the url and it is perfectly fine. And the code is where i am getting the error (short snippet)

```
WWW www = new WWW (getURL);
yield return www;

if (www.error != null)
{
    Debug.Log("Error" + www.error);
}
```

Comment: `There is nothing illegal i have logged the url and it is perfectly fine.` Well the exception suggests otherwise. Please show us the line of code that throws the exception. Please update your post to include the actual value of `getURL` and `doneURL`.

Comment: Just because it _looks_ “perfectly fine”, it doesn’t actually have to be - you might be dealing with “invisible” characters. Apply URL- or HEX-encoding to the value before you make a debug output, that will help you to see which actual byte values are occurring where.

Comment: @mjwills i have added the code. can you please check it

Comment: @CBroe apply URL or Hex-encoding ? check this how to do

Comment: actually it is getURL variable. i directly access it. i have already given

Comment: What does `url[0].Length` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect a `\r` to be at the end of your Url if your txt file was saved on a Windows box as it defaults to `\r\n` to separate lines. Use the [`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead. It does handle line endings with respect to the OS default.

```
string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/" + urlFile;
// read all lines, and let the Framework do the split in lines
// it is much better at it.
string[] url = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); // <<--- HERE IS YOUR SOLUTION!!!!!
string getURL = url[0];//this is the url
string doneURL = url[1];
```

You get the same error as described in [Using curl in a bash script and getting curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018899/using-curl-in-a-bash-script-and-getting-curl-3-illegal-characters-found-in-ur) (thanks @mjwills for pointing that out) and the solution offered there for the bash script is the same as what I propose in this C# solution. I haven't found a confirmation that Unity3D's [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class actually uses the [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) library as their implementation but it seems a viable assumption.

Comment: what is the solution? where is the solution?